# How to call AJAX when new notification comes with codeigniter and nodejs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js, codeigniter

Currently I've notification system in my current application and which is working with AJAX call in SetInterval what I want is to now implement same with nodejs, if any new notification comes then node should call that AJAX or something similar to that, I never worked with NodeJS before but by some learing I write some codes but I would like to know little more about its event and how to do it.

Currently I'm calling nodejs from PHP like this :

```
<?php echo `node node-server/server.js` ?>
```

and NodeJS code :

```
var http = require('http');
var sockjs = require('sockjs');
var echo = sockjs.createServer();
var server = http.createServer();
echo.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/notification'});
server.listen(9999, 'localhost');
```

its giving me message :

> SockJS v0.3.5 bound to "/notification"

But its not enough for my purpose, please let me know what more I've to do for it ?

TIA

Comment: So it almost sounds like you need to find a sockjs tutorial/example to learn how to use it?  If not, can you clarify what you are asking?  I don't see any code to process the message received from sockjs.

Comment: This is not how node is supposed to be used. Please start with an introductory node tutorial.

Comment: is it somehow related web workers..I guess

Comment: You can use node.js + socket.io, you have thousands of tutorials about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no experience with sockjs (i used socket.io) but i can give some hints:

1. You can have a listener in server php code in which you use
   something like [redis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) . Then publish in a channel with an encoded payload of the notification.
2. In your nodejs server script you require redis and subscribe to the
   same channel as above
   Each time a message is published with sockjs you can then emit to your php client application (i mean the view via js) to notify the user that something new came, you can use library like https://github.com/sciactive/pnotify

As suggested in comment you google socket.io and take a look of tutorial and adapt it to your fit with sockjs.
Hope it's helped